# Get encryption status of external SD card on android

Tags: android, adt

I am writing an app that provides option to encrypt,clear devices and sd cards registered to the app. I was able to test the encryption status of the device using

```
getStorageEncryptionStatus ()
```

Now I do not know how to check the encryption status of the external SD card in the device. Is there any function which is similar to getStorageEncryptionStatus() for the SD cards?